# IntelliJ Idea can not resolve same method in super class and interface

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Here i'm reading `spring-security-oauth2` source code and found there was a compile error in `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer`. 
below is the capture of such error:
[image: error hint]
**this is errors Idea gives** : `Ambiguous method call: both AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.getConfigurer(..) and HttpSecurityBuilder matches`

But i know abstract class can implements methods both exists in its super class and interface in Java. but Idea do not know, **how can i remove such error hint**(having obsession about such red color).

At last, this is the hierarchy generated by Idea about class `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer`:
[image: hierarchy]